# Nginx return static file or proxied request depending on cookie value

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have two applications, one nodejs and another react app. I user is not logged in, I return the node app, if user is logged in, I want to return the react app `index.html` file.

```
location / {
    if ($cookie_isLoggedIn = "true") {
        // how can I return the index.html file here ?
    }
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

What I tried so far:

1. `rewrite ^/$ /platform-build/index.html;` - doesn't do anything.
2. `alias` and `root` are not working inside `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two different content handlers (`proxy_pass` and `try_files`), so you need two different locations for that. You can return some static HTML content via the directive like

```
return 200 "<body>Hello, world!</body>";
```

but I don't think it will satisfy your needs. However you can use the following trick (taken from [this](https://serverfault.com/a/965779/498657) answer):

```
map $cookie_isLoggedIn $loc {
    true    react;
    default node;
}
server {
    ...
    location / {
        try_files /dev/null @$loc;
    }
    location @react {
        root /your/react/app/root;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location @node {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

The author of original trick says it doesn't have any performance impact.

Comment: @Valera I renamed your question a little to make it easier to find by others, if you don't mind.